# How can the Debian DVD .iso file be used to install software without a CD Drive or the Internet?

Tags: debian, software-installation, dvd

**Question Background:**

1. I donot have a CD-Drive
2. I downloaded Debian DVD Wheezy 64 Bit
3. Installed Basic Utilities + Desktop by usb boot
4. NOW I want to install more software

**Problem:**

`apt-get install vlc`
It says insert dvd in DVD drive which i donot have.
I mounted the iso file but didnot work.
**I donot want use internet to download the software**.

**Question:**

How the iso file can be used to install software with out CD Drive & Internet???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the ISO, you can mount it as a loop device:

```
sudo mount -t iso9660 -o loop PATH/TO/ISO /cdrom
```

and keep the cdrom entry in your sources.list.

Note that apt sources are kept current with bugs fixes, version updates and so forth. To 
get remote (network based sources), you will just need to edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and remove/comment out the cd entries:

```
deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.0.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20130504-14:44]/ wheezy contrib man
```

You may also need to add external entries for apt:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian wheezy main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian wheezy main non-free contrib
```

It is also worth while keeping up to date with security updates:

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
```

Comment: That is really nice, But **CANNOT I USE THE DOWNLOADED 4 GB ISO IMAGE!!!**

Comment: Updated my answer, sorry I didn't read the question properly :P

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to copy the ISO directly to a usb flash drive and set your computer to boot first from usb (usually <kbd>F12</kbd> when the computer is first booting). According to the [official debian site](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch04s03.html.en), you can just copy to usb and install that way, so long as you already have a linux system running.

If you don't have an existing linux OS already running, or know someone who can make the usb install stick for you, then you will probably have to use a iso creation program to installt he ISO correctly and make it "[bootable](https://wiki.debian.org/BootUsb)."